# Evaluating conditional probability and expectations on event

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

Suppose we have a natural filtration $\{\mathcal{F}_n\}$ of a stochastic process $\{X_n\}$ and an event $A$ in a supporting probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$. Often certain distributional properties of the process are stated in the following form: $\mathbb{P}(A|\mathcal{F}_n)=f(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$ on some event $E$, which is measurable with respect to $\mathcal{F}_n$.

My question is: what is the intuition behind such type of proposition, in particular behind evaluating the conditional probability on an event. We know that for example this has a very specific meaning when the filtration is generated by a partition and the event is in one of the partitioning sets. In this case the evaluation turns the conditional probability into an elementary conditioning on the part of the partition containing the event $E$. But what about the more general case, when the sigma-algebra is not generated by a partition? Is there still a heuristic way to understand the evaluation of the conditional probability on the event $E$?

Comment: Which proposition exactly?

Comment: Not sure if I follow your question. If $E_1,\dots,E_n$ partition $\Omega$ with $E_i\in \mathcal G$, then $E(X\mid \mathcal G) = E(X\mid E_i)$ on $E_i$, provided the right hand side is well-defined.

Comment: @AndrewZhang Yes, that is the meaning of the claim, but only if $\mathcal{G}=\sigma (E_1,\ldots,E_n)$. Which is what I wrote. My question refers to the case in which, in your notation, $\mathcal{G}$ is not of such form (a sigma algebra need not be generated by a partitioning).

Comment: @SBF The one after the colon, at the end of the first paragraph.

Comment: Correct me if I’m wrong, but it still holds regardless if $\mathcal G$ is generated by a partition or not. Perhaps it would be better just to state that if $E\in \mathcal G$ has positive probability, then $$E(X\mid \mathcal G)= E(X\mid E) = E(X;E)/P(E)$$ on $E$.

Comment: @AndrewZhang I am not sure this is true, in general, does it follow from the property $\int_E \mathbb{E}(X|\mathcal{G})=\int_E X$?

Comment: @AndrewZhang I think it dos not hold because of the following counterexample: take $X,Y$ i.i.d. $Unif(0,1)$. Calculate $\mathbb{E}(X+Y|Y)$ and $\mathbb{E}(X+Y|Y\leq 1/2)$. Clearly $(Y\leq 1/2)\in\sigma(Y)$. So if your claim were true, for every $\omega\in(Y\leq 1/2)$, we would have $1/2+Y(\omega)=\mathbb{E}(X+Y|Y)(\omega)=\mathbb{E}(X+Y|Y\leq 1/2)=1/2+1/4$. This is clearly not true for $\omega\in(Y<1/4)\subset (Y\leq 1/2)$, thus we have a contradiction.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I deleted my answer.

Comment: @AndrewZhang Note that my counterexample worked because the set $(Y\leq 1/2)$ gives me enough freedom. If we where to consider a stricter set such as $(Y=x)$ for any $x\in[0,1]$ it would not work. In fact I could show that your interpretation works only on sets of such special form (even for general random variables, not just discrete, with the due interpretations regarding conditioning).